# VSTS : Invalidating builds on existing PRs when another commit makes it into master branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have setup a build policy as part of our CI pipeline into master branch. The policy ensures that the PR changes + master head builds successfully before squash merging the PR changes into master.

We came across a situation today where two separate change lists (which have no merge conflicts with master and among themselves) made it into master branch, but when the second change list completed, the rolling master build failed.

Upon analyzing, we noticed that the second PR already had succeeded the build policy before the first PR was completed. Hence the second PR never built with now new head and current changes prior to merging to master which would have caught the issue.

Hence the question, how to invalidate all builds on open PRs when another commit goes into master.

Comment: Let's confirm the situation: Do you have two pull request for different branches to merge to master? Then a pull request complete and merged, then you want to complete another pull request and merge conflict. Am I right?

Comment: How about set build expiration in pull request policy?

Comment: There were no merge conflicts. I updated the build expiration to "immediately" as suggested in the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the `Branches` section, click the ellipses next to master and select `Branch policies`.

Then add a `Build Validation` policy.  Link to a existing build definition and then set the following fields:

- *Trigger*: **Automatic**
- *Policy Requirement*: **Required**
- *Build expiration*: **Immediately**

This way PRs targeting master will always require a new build whenever either the feature branch is update *or* master is updated, ie a different PR was accepted into master.

My guess, based on your description, is you have `Build expiration` set to something other than *Immediately*, thus when PR 1 got merged to master, PR 2's build was not correctly expired, so VSTS didn't require the PR 2 to be rebuilt and instead allowed PR 2 to be merged.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: Follow up question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455911/vsts-automatically-rebase-merge-and-requeue-build-validation-gate-in-case-of-b?noredirect=1&lq=1